# How to read an HTML page line by line using php?

Tags: html, php-5.3

How to read an HTML page line by line using php. I have to add and edit some file paths of my html page using php.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a DOM parser instead of reading line-by-line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you explicitly want to read a HTML file line by line, use a DOM parser.

Otherwise, if for some reason you do want to read it line by line, split the contents by newline `\n` (should be, you may want to normalise other newline types like `\r\n`) and then iterate through the resulting array.

Comment: IIRC, `file()` does what your second paragraphs suggests.

Answer (score 2):

I can't agree more with alex. But i can recommend http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/